# dynamic_cast across a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, shared-ptr, dynamic-cast

I have two classes A and B, B inherits from A.

If I have a `shared_ptr<A>` object which I know is really a B subtype, how can I perform a dynamic cast to access the API of B (bearing in mind my object is shared_ptr, not just A?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If you just want to call a function from `B` you can use one of these:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> ap = ...;
dynamic_cast<B&>(*ap).b_function();
if (B* bp = dynamic_cast<B*>(ap.get()) {
    ...
}
```

In case you actually want to get a `std::shared_ptr<B>` from the `std::shared_ptr<A>`, you can use use

```
std::shared_ptr<B> bp = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(ap);
```

Comment: `dynamic_cast<B&>(*ap).b_function();` if you are doing this, what is the point of the dynamic_cast. You don't check the result anyway, you would just use `static_cast` here. I think only the `if(B* bp = ...` and the `dynamic_pointer_cast` are correct here.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox: a `static_cast<B*>(a)` can only be used if `a` was obtained from an implicit conversion from a `B*`. Of the conversion was from a further derived type or from a sibling class in a scenario involving multiple inheritance the `dynamic_cast` has defined behavior while the `static_cast` has not.

Comment: `dynamic_pointer_cast` was exactly what I was looking for (as opposed to `dynamic_cast`)

Comment: @FantasticMrFox You don't need to check the result of the dynamic_cast on reference types... how/what would you check?  The specified behavior of dynamic_cast is to throw a std::bad_cast exception when casting references would fail.

Answer (score 23):

use [`dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/dynamic_pointer_cast/)

example copied from above link

```
// static_pointer_cast example
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A {
  static const char* static_type;
  const char* dynamic_type;
  A() { dynamic_type = static_type; }
};
struct B: A {
  static const char* static_type;
  B() { dynamic_type = static_type; }
};

const char* A::static_type = "class A";
const char* B::static_type = "class B";

int main () {
  std::shared_ptr<A> foo;
  std::shared_ptr<B> bar;

  bar = std::make_shared<B>();

  foo = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<A>(bar);

  std::cout << "foo's static  type: " << foo->static_type << '\n';
  std::cout << "foo's dynamic type: " << foo->dynamic_type << '\n';
  std::cout << "bar's static  type: " << bar->static_type << '\n';
  std::cout << "bar's dynamic type: " << bar->dynamic_type << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

output

```
foo's static  type: class A
foo's dynamic type: class B
bar's static  type: class B
bar's dynamic type: class B
```

Comment: That example doesn't even need any cast.

Comment: Bryan, I cannot plus one you enough for this answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the nicest way would be to [use the standard functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) for casting a `shared_ptr`