# Dynamic cast from base to derived class in order to access a method

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++14, dynamic-cast

I have access to a base class `PlayerBase`, from which I have derived the class `Player`. There also exists another class, `GameEventHandler`, that is responsible for actually delegating "resources" to each player, with the  mehtod `GameEventhandler::ModifyResource`:

```
bool GameEventHandler::modifyResource(std::shared_ptr<Course::PlayerBase> player,
                                      Course::BasicResource resource,
                                      int amount)
{

}
```

However, the implementation of this method has been left up to me, as you can see.

The problem is as follows: only the derived class `Player` has a method `Player::increaseResource`, that can increase one of its resources. However, the method `modifyResource` takes a shared pointer to a `PlayerBase` object as a parameter. This means, that in order to access the method `Player::increaseResource`, I would have to cast the `Playerbase` type pointer to a `Player` type pointer, or do some other trickery.

How does one handle this type of situation? I've tried something like

```
std::shared_ptr<Player> ownPlayerPtr
    = dynamic_cast<std::shared_ptr<Player>>(player);
```

but this gives the error `std::shared_ptr<Player>` is nmot a reference to a pointer. Changing this to

```
std::shared_ptr<Player> ownPlayerPtr
    = dynamic_cast<std::shared_ptr<Player>&>(player);
```

gives the error message `'std::shared_ptr<Course::PlayerBase>' is not polymorphic = dynamic_cast<std::shared_ptr<Player>&>(player);`.

Any ideas as to why this is happening and what I would need to do to fix this?

Comment: [`dynamic_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795265/dynamic-cast-across-a-shared-ptr).

Try to use dynamic_pointer_cast:

```
std::shared_ptr<Course::Player> p = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Course::Player>(player);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic cast of shared pointer instead.
If shared pointer is not empty, and such a cast would not return a null pointer, the returned object shares ownership over shared pointer's resources, increasing by one the use count.
Otherwise, the returned object is an empty shared_ptr.
i.e
std::shared_ptr ownPlayerPtr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast(player).